# Principled volume showing up in viewport, but not cycles render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, volumetrics, shader-nodes

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? (I'm not great with shaders lol so any advice would be very helpful)

Comment: you mean you don't see it if you make a final render?

Comment: Yep, do you have a solution?

Comment: no, I was just asking because it was not clear, but maybe share your file (just the cube with the Principled Volume)? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/e10a24312d924bae9352109755a2f65d here

Answer (score 0):

You've disabled the render option in the *Outliner* (or *Object panel > Visibility > Renders*):

[image]

Comment: lol how did i not notice that, tysm

Comment: @Raccoon This site is not a regular forum, don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).